# Excluding tags isn't working whatsoever at all

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, new-nav, tag-search

In both the [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav) and the old search the following query doesn't work:

> [feature-request] -[status-completed]

In [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav) it doesn't work **at all** (note the first result is only tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion))

[image]

and clicking <kbd>all</kbd> just changes it to

> [feature-request] [status-completed]

[image]

and in old nav it gets changed to just

> [feature-request]

[image]

Like I literally typed the first search query into the top right search bar and got redirected to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request

Soo... what's up? Am I trying to run an invalid search query? Or is search really *this* broken? :S